# Using traffic_model with arrival_time

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

When I was trying to get pessimistic travel time to get on specific time to a destination I get an error:
{
   "error_message" : "Invalid request. Missing the 'departure_time' parameter.",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
My request is: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?units=metric&origin=Split&destination=Solin&mode=driving&language=hr&arrival_time=1518969600&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=*KEY*

When I'm using departure_time instead of arrival_time or when I don't use traffic_model (then it defaults to "best_guess") option then I get results just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `arrival time` can only be specified for `travel mode = transit`.

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) said:

> The departure time may be specified in two cases:
>
> For requests where the travel mode is transit: You can optionally
>   specify one of departure_time or arrival_time. If neither time is
>   specified, the departure_time defaults to now (that is, the departure
>   time defaults to the current time).
>
> For requests where the travel mode is driving: You can specify the
>   departure_time to receive a route and trip duration (response field:
>   duration_in_traffic) that take traffic conditions into account. This
>   option is only available if the request contains a valid API key, or a
>   valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature. The
>   departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the
>   future. It cannot be in the past.

Arrival time will be ignored if given for other requests.

You can try yourself to make your request for transit mode and arrival time:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?units=metric&origin=Split&destination=Solin&mode=transit&language=hr&arrival_time=1518969600&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=YOURKEY